# Can't reference system.drawing.dll

Tags: c#, system.drawing, imageresizer

i'm trying to resize images with ImageResizer, but keep getting a compilation error

> "Error    1 The type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' is defined in an assembly
>   that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Drawing"

Searching for a solution i find several similar questions where the solution is to reference system.drawing.dll to be able to handle images, but when i tried referencing it by:

rightclick project -> add reference -> select COM  ->find the system.drawing.dll

but this gives me another error saying "the activeX type library system.drawing.tlb was exported froma  .NET assembly and cannot be added as a reference. Add a reference to the .NET assebly instead"

And this is where i'm left dumbfounded as what to do next.

Edit:

code where i get the error

```
public void resizeImage(String originalFile, String thumb)
    {
        ResizeSettings r = new ResizeSettings();
        r.MaxHeight = 200;
        r.MaxWidth = 200;


      ImageBuilder.Current.Build(originalFile, thumb, r);//this is where i get the first error
    }
```

Comment: System.Anything is going be a .NET assembly. The error message tells you that. So add your reference from the .NET tab of that dialog.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Add it from the .NET tab, not the COM tab.

In the Solution Explorer tab Of Visual Studio, right click on References and select "Add Reference...". Then click Assemblies, Framework, and scroll down until you see System.Drawing. Click the checkbox next to it, then click OK

Comment: Update: In Visual Studio 2012 it is under `Assemblies > Framework`

Comment: Kartiikeya, in the Solution Explorer tab, right click on References and select "Add Reference...". Then click Assemblies, Framework, and scroll down until you see System.Drawing. Click the checkbox next to it, then click OK.